# What is the best way to implode arrays in nested hash

Tags: ruby

I am searching for the most convenient way how to implode arrays to strings in hash in ruby. Arrays can be only in the first level.

Here is the hash

```
{"type"=>["Auto"], "mark"=>["Skoda","VW"], "page-size"=>"5", "page"=>"1"}
```

and I expect to get

```
{"type"=>"Auto", "mark"=>"Skoda, VW", "page-size"=>"5", "page"=>"1"}
```

I'm currently using:

```
params.each do |k,v|
  params[k] = v.join(' ') if v.is_a?(Array)
end
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried, if anything

Comment: @CarlMarkham 
params.each do |k,v|
   params[k] = v.join(' ') if v.is_a?(Array)
end

Comment: `hash.each { |k,v| hash[k] = v.join(', ') if v.is_a?(Array) }`

Comment: @anotherh, that does mutate the hash, yet the OP has not said if that is permitted. I think we should state assumptions or a proviso in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = {"type"=>["Auto"], "mark"=>["Skoda", "VW"], "page-size"=>"5",
     "page"=>"1"}
```

```
h.transform_values { |v| [v].join(' ') }
  #=> {"type"=>"Auto", "mark"=>"Skoda VW", "page-size"=>"5",
  #    "page"=>"1"}
```

See [Hash#tranform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). This returns a new hash without mutating the existing one.

See also [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join), particularly, "For nested arrays, join is applied recursively".

Note:

```
[["Skoda VW"]].join(' ')
  #=> "Skoda VW" 

["5"].join(' ')
  #=> "5"
```

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you want to join with a comma:

One liner:

```
hash.each {|k, v| hash[k] = v.join(', ') if v.is_a? Array }
```

More readable:

```
hash.map do |k, v| 
  hash[k] = v.join(', ') if v.is_a? Array
end
```